# How to make TreeNode in Ant tree design as link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a tree design from Ant Design, got everything done, but at some specific places I want the tree node to act as link, tried giving link directly, that didn't work.

```
array.map((node) => {
   if(node.type !== 'last') {
      <TreeNode title={item.name} key={item.id} dataRef={item} />
   } else{
      <Link className="container" to={{ pathname: 'somepath'}}></Link>
  }
```

})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you need, but maybe pass Link as a title:

```
<TreeNode
    title={<Link className="container" to={{ pathname: 'somepath'}}>{item.name}</Link>}
    key={item.id}
    dataRef={item}
/>
```

is good enough?

Also there is `onCheck` and `onSelect` callbacks in [TreeNode api](https://ant.design/components/tree/), which can do redirect to specific url, i.e.:

```
class LinkAbleTreeNode extends PureComponent {
  onCheck = () => {
    props.history.push(props.url)
  }

  render() {
    return <TreeNode title={item.name} key={item.id} dataRef={item} onCheck={this.onCheck} />
  }
}

export default withRouter(LinkAbleTreeNode);
```

And pass url as a prop:

```
<LinkAbleTreeNode /*...tree node args... */ url='somepath' />
```

This solution require [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) [hoc](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to be added into application. But if you have available the router props in parent component, you can just pass them through.

**UPDATE**

For antd v4 only pass `title` prop with custom component is the acceptable solution.

Comment: Did something change? I get `Warning: Tree only accept TreeNode as children.` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-elgamal-e2y6x?file=/index.js)

Comment: @HMR, yes, at least major version (4.x.x) of antd was released. When the answer was posted [v3](https://3x.ant.design/components/tree/) was the latest. Version 4 seems to not allow to go with custom tree node component. However, you're still allowed to pass a `Link` (or custom) component as `title` prop of `TreeNode`.